# Asp.Net Core 2.0 Mvc template processing failed: The types 'List<>' could not be found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Have an Asp.net core 1.1 Mvc app that I converted to 2.0 that includes a custom Templates/ folder.  When I attempt to add a controller w EF actions, I get the following error:

[image: Template processing failed...]

I assume there are updated templates for core 2.0 but don't know where to find them.

Answer (score 1):

Make the following modifications:

**Templates\ControllerGenerator\MvcControllerWithContext.cshtml**

Add :

```
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Linq;
```

in addition of :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

So the 'header' looks like :

```
@inherits Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Templating.RazorTemplateBase
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

**Templates\ViewGenerator\List.cshtml**

Add :

```
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Linq;
```

so the 'header' looks like :

```
@inherits Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Templating.RazorTemplateBase
@using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.EntityFrameworkCore
@using System.Collections.Generic
@using System.Linq
@@model @GetEnumerableTypeExpression(Model.ViewDataTypeName)
```

Then make the following replacement :

```
IEnumerable<PropertyMetadata> var properties = Model.ModelMetadata.Properties;
```

Sources:

https://forums.asp.net/p/2128119/6164188.aspx?Re+Migration+1+1+to+2+0+Scaffold+multiple+problems

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/